# Maintain node order column in SQL/MySql closure tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, insert, transitive-closure-table

I have read and used http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/02/14/moving-subtrees-in-closure-table/ and http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data, but does not solve my problem.

My question is:

How is it possible to maintain a integer column which describes how a given node is ordered with respect to other nodes of same depth in a closure table structure?

Currently, I am using the following sql statement to insert new tree nodes which is working as expected:

```
INSERT INTO data_tree (anc, des, depth)
  SELECT t.anc, :nodeValue0, t.depth+1
FROM data_tree AS t
  WHERE t.des = :insertedAt
UNION ALL
  SELECT :nodeValue1, :nodeValue2, 0
```

I have thought about some different solution, but cant see the solution. One idea is to 'calculate' the node order for a given depth in a sql trigger on each insert.
Another solution is to update the above statement to support directly update of the depth order, such as:

```
INSERT INTO data_tree (anc, des, depth)
  SELECT t.anc, :nodeValue0, t.depth+1, --> t1.depthOrder <--
FROM data_tree AS t
  --> JOIN data_tree t1 'where the node order can be determined from' <--
  WHERE t.des = :insertedAt
UNION ALL
  SELECT :nodeValue1, :nodeValue2, 0, 0
```

Have anybody tried this, and how can it be solved?

Comment: Can some one please close this, as the answer can be found here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069674/sorting-a-subtree-in-a-closure-table-hierarchical-data-structure/14074310#14074310). Bill Karwin saves the day again :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting a subtree in a closure table hierarchical-data structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069674/sorting-a-subtree-in-a-closure-table-hierarchical-data-structure)