# Mysql Closure table address descendant in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, closures, transitive-closure-table

I have Post Table

`+----+-------+--------------+
| Id | Name  | Message      |
+====+=======+==============+
| 1  | John  | John's msg   |
| 2  | Marco | Marco's msg  |
| 3  | Ivan  | Ivan's msg   |
+----+-------+--------------+`

Comment table, PostId is foreign key

```
+----+-------+--------------+--------+
| Id | Name  | Comment      | PostId |
+====+=======+==============+========+
| 1  | John  | John's msg   | 2      |
| 2  |Joseph |Joseph's msg  | 2      |
| 3  | Ivan  | Ivan's msg   | 2      |
| 4  |Natalie|Natalie's msg | 1      |
+----+-------+--------------+--------+
```

Created closure table to keep comment hierarchy as described at:
http://karwin.blogspot.ba/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html

Closure table

`+----------+-------------+
| ancestor | descendant  |
+==========+=============+
| 1        | 1           |
| 1        | 2           |
| 1        | 3           |
| 4        | 4           |
+----------+-------------+`

In order to create ancestor>descendant relation in PHP I 
use this query

```
`select c.* from comments c join closure t on (c.id = t.descendant ) where c.postid=2`
```

I get result with 1st 3 comments from comment table.
But i want to display this on web page like this:

```
Post Id=2
    Comment id=1
        Comment id=2
        Comment id=3
```

I don't know how to tell PHP who is ancestor and who is 
descendant. This is my best try:

```
$sql = "select c.* from comments c join closure t on 
(c.id = t.descendant ) where c.postId=2";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Name: " . $row["name"]."". "Message:" . $row["comment"].";
       }
} else {
    echo "No comments yet";
}
```

But it only shows all comments in line. Need a way to identify when comment is descendant.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
if (ascendant){
    echo "ascendant comment"
}
else{
    echo "tab"."descendant comment"
}
}
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that you did not faithfully produce a complete closure table above, this question was asked and answered more than four years before this post in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069674/sorting-a-subtree-in-a-closure-table-hierarchical-data-structure/14074310#14074310