# Is that many-to-many sql relationship?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I have two tables:

```
A (id, name) 
B (idA1, idA2, ...)
```

Combination of `idA1` and `idA2` is a primary key. At the same time `idA1` and `idA2` are foreign keys to `tableA`.

Is that many-to-many relationship?

Comment: Yes, this sounds like a many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  With the info provided, there's nothing there to prevent multiple distinct idA2 values appearing in B combined with the same idA1 value, and there's also nothing in there to prevent multiple distinct idA1 values appearing in B combined with the same idA2 value. So each id appearing in A can potentially be associated with many other id values in A (through idA1 -> idA2) as well as in the other direction (through idA2 -> idA1).

Answer (score 0):

This is a many-to-many relationship, with a specificity is that both the referencing and referenced tables are the same.

Basically, each record in `tableA` may refer to 0, 1 or several records in the same table, through bridge table `tableB`.

One comparison that comes to mind is a representation of a tree, where `tableA` stores the nodes and `tableB` is a *closure table*, that stores all possible hierarchy paths (as explained for example in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14069674/10676716)).

`nodes` table:

```
id    name
1     foo
2     bar
3     baz
4     zoo
```

`paths` table:

```
parent    child
1         1
1         2
1         3
1         4
2         3
2         4
```

Which represents a tree like:

```
  1
  |
  2
 / \
3   4
```