# Mysql number-string formatting

Tags: mysql

I have a column named unique_id which can take values,

```
16-01
16-10,
16-250,
16-1594
```

etc

16 is the year(eg.2016) and 01 is a count for something in this year. I manage to get this format using a BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER.
Now I want to have 4 char format in count number like

```
16-0001
16-0010
16-0250
16-1594
```

How can I manage this formatting?

Comment: do you want to update old records in database?

Comment: Similar question: [Adding a leading zero to some values in column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165104/adding-a-leading-zero-to-some-values-in-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LPAD(yourcolumn, 4, '0')`;)

```
select
    concat(left(data,3), lpad(substring(data, 4), 4, '0'))
from test
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b10e4/2)

And check manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad).

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Column1=concat(left(Column1,3), lpad(substring(Column1, 4), 4, '0'));
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6fa7c/2)

Alternatively, RegEx may be used to replace using [MYSQL UDF](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp).

Comment: I think there is no big difference between `UPDATE` and `SELECT`, and what I've provided is just a way to solve problem, if you agree with that, you can upvote it, there is no need post this again here.

Comment: I agree. No  difference for me If it's select or update

Comment: you can do this update using https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp

Comment: @PatroklosPatroklou sorry I felt it was the answer to the question as a SELECT merely prints the output rather than update the table.