# Add zeros at beginning of a number if it is small than 1000

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, numbers

I have an SQL Query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS tot_std  
FROM `login`  
WHERE `login_account_type` =
'STUDENT'
```

The output of this query is 9.

What I want is to add:

- Three zeros if the number is small than 10, like 0009.
- Two zeros if the number is small than 99, like 0099,
- One zero if the number is smaller than 999, like 0999.
- If the number is equal to or greater than 1000, don't add any zero.

Note that I am using PHP Codeigniter and MySQL for the project.

Please Help.

Comment: Are you asking for a PHP solution or a MySQL solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a leading zero to some values in column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165104/adding-a-leading-zero-to-some-values-in-column)

Comment: Any. If it is possible with MySQL, it would be better. If not, I would try it with PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Try the below code

**In your query, you can do like**

```
SELECT LPAD(COUNT(*),4,'0') AS tot_std FROM login WHERE login_account_type = 'STUDENT'
```

**In PHP**

```
$your_value = 9;
$your_value = str_pad($your_value,4,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $your_value;
```

`str_pad()` function will add leading zeros. The `second parameter` shows the total number. As you need it for thousands, I add 4. The `3rd parameter` represent which character added at the beginning. The `fourth parameter` is the side where you need to add the zero

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
  "SELECT lpad(tot_std,4,0) as tot_std FROM login WHERE login_account_type='STUDENT'" ;
```

Comment: I tried this query but it does not work: SELECT COUNT(*) AS tot_std, LPAD(tot_std, 4, 0) AS lpad_std 
FROM `login` 
WHERE `login_account_type` = 'STUDENT'

Comment: "SELECT lpad(tot_std,4,0) as tot_std FROM login WHERE login_account_type='STUDENT'" ;