# Display id with zero as starting number

Tags: mysql

I have an `id` column in my `employee` table in my database. Now for example I have to use 000001 as an `id`. It only shows 1.

I've used the datatype `int` for the `id` column. My question is, are there any other datatypes that would let me show the zeroes instead of varchar.

Comment: See this one http://geekswithblogs.net/nagendraprasad/archive/2009/03/19/formatting-number-to-add-leading-zeros---sql-server.aspx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165104/adding-a-leading-zero-to-some-values-in-column